# SPMonitoredScope doesn't work as expected

Tags: best-practices

my code:

```
using (new SPMonitoredScope("Sleepy Time", 1000)) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

when I enable the Developer Dashboard, I am expecting a red border around it because the code running in the monitored scope is running longer than 1000 milliseconds.

But it doesn't happen. I do get a bullet point in the Developer Dashboard such as

- Sleepy Time (5008.26 ms)

but no indication that the counter was triggered.
Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

DD only show you the standard events called by SharePoint. Eg OnPreRender, CreateChildControls etc.

If you want to add monitors to a web part, you would need to create a method like this

```
private void SleepyTime()
{
    using (SPMonitoredScope scope = new SPMonitoredScope("SleepyTime"))
    {                
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

and it would show up in DD from the overridden event from which the method was called
CreateChildControls (50xx ms)
- SleepyTime (5000 ms)

Note that the code above wont run in a sandboxed solution!

You can also create a custom monitored scope using the ISPScopedPerformanceMonitor interface. This is used in conjunction with an overridden constructor

```
int maxExecutionTime = 1000; // The maximum duration of the monitoring operation, in milliseconds
using (SPMonitoredScope scope = new SPMonitoredScope("SleepyTime", maxExecutionTime, new MyCustomMonitor()))
{
    // MyCustomMonitor implements ISPScopedPerformanceMonitor interface
    // If monitoring the scope exceeds the time represented by the maximumExecutionTime value, you can use the maximumExecutionTime value to increase the logging level.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The red border is only triggered by SharePoint defined monitors at the root scope. A yellow border should indicate that the request took more than one second.